# Network meta-analysis - Why is confidence interval changed relative to pairwise comparison when only direct evidence exists?

Tags: meta-analysis, network-meta-analysis

I have a basic question about network meta-analysis (NMA). If a comparison between nodes is based completely on direct evidence with no indirect evidence, does that mean that no other interventions are contributing to the result of the comparison in the NMA result? In other words, if A vs B is known to be based on 100% of direct evidence as there are no indirect paths to that comparison (i.e., the indirect pathway of A vs C followed by C vs B does not exist), do contributions to the B node from other interventions (e.g., from comparisons of C vs B, D vs B, E vs) influence the comparison A vs B in any way? I ask this since it is clear that the confidence interval of the A vs B comparison (but not the summary measure itself) is quite different between the pairwise comparison to the NMA result so I am wondering where that comes from. I thought it might be due to heterogeneity but there is only a single study contributing to A vs B, so presumably no heterogeneity is not defined). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which method are you using to do the meta-analysis? Beware than generally in NMA you consider the same tau2 for all the network and not a different tau2 for every comparison, so you have different heterogeneity estimation between pairwise and network.

Comment: If you provide a sample dataset and suitable codes it would be helpful to answer your question. In addition, what package are you using?

Comment: To clarify, I am using random-effects model in Stata (metan package). I have values for the tau2 over the whole network and also over each pairwise comparison. So even if there is only one study comprised of direct evidence in a particular pairwise comparison within the NMA, the network heterogeneity contributes to the uncertainty of that comparison?